# Removed app in google play

Tags: android, google-play, blocked

I have uploaded an application in google play and it has been blocked because the meta data was not compliant with the content agreement of google play. I have read the content policies more carefully and now I want to re-enable the application with the new data. The problem is that I cannot find the way to do this and in google play I could not find anything useful.

Please help if anyone knows the steps to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a Google technical support issue, not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reupload your application as new with different id. Google never re-enable app after it was blocked.